# Arch linux not visible in bootloader

Tags: arch-linux, boot-loader, refind

I installed Arch following the [beginers guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide) and installed the rEFInd bootloader. When i start my computer rEFInd can load windows and the Arch live cd (if it's inserted) but i cant get it to show arch. Also, there is no `arch` or `arch.efi` in my boot partition, but `initramfs-linux.img` is there. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to stay with rEFInd, it requires additional setup for voting Arch Linux via UEFI. I would highly recommend reading it's wiki page here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/REFInd .

I personally would recommend using GRUB along with os-prober to find your windows installation. GRUB is, at least in my own usage, far easier to use than rEFInd, and os-prober automagically finds windows for you.

Comment: Thanks, although this is almost 3 years old now. My current boot loader of choice is systemd boot.